# Update an array of records with Rails and Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Let's say we have a multiple lists of items.

```
<ul data-id="2">
    <li>
        <span>Item name</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item name</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item name</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Each item has a `list_id` attribute which is the ID of the list the item currently belongs to and an `order` attribute which is the item's current position in the list.

When a certain event occurs, we want to find each item in this list and update its `list_id` and `order` parameters.

Here's what I have so far

```
$('li').sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {

            var cards = ui.item.parent('ul li').map(function() {
                return {
                    list_id: $(this).closest('ul').data('id'),
                    order: $(this).index(),
                }
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/cards/",
                type: "PATCH",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { cards: cards },
                success: function(resp){
                    console.log('Yay');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I'm having trouble outputting the cards array anywhere. When I run `console.log(cards);` I just get `[]` with no data I can understand. My rails console doesn't seem to outputting any params array either.

The goal is to send all the cards in the list to my rails controller and update them all simultaneously.

Comment: Please complete your script.

Comment: Add the whole data involved, where does `ui` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. I'm using jQuery Sortable to drag the list items. The update function is called when a list item is released.

Answer (score 0):

The first question, why you select `li` tag for sortable instead of `ul` tag?

> Enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable

You should select `ul` tag instead of `li`.

```js
$('ul').sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        var list_id = $(this).data('id');
        var cards = $.map($(this).find('li'), function(el) {
            return { list_id: list_id,
                      order: $(el).index() };
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cards/",
            type: "PATCH",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { cards: cards },
            success: function(resp){
                console.log('Yay');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 60%;
}
li {
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 0.4em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #454545;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul data-id="2">
    <li>
        <span>Item name</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item name 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item name 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Originally, I recreated the markup to simplify the question. Here is the actual markup with your function applied. https://gist.github.com/colmtuite/6b26191a23b9ec57f70fa6b3818ab892

Comment: I'm primarily interested in outputting the parameters in the console log, so I can see what type of data/array I'm working with, so I can then figure out how to pass that to Rails. Can you help with that?

Comment: @colmtuite If you have problem, you should explain to the other people with the actual markup, so people can help you with actual solution. Your first question is about trouble outputting the cards.

Comment: @colmtuite the output of cards in my script is an array of object, it can be process with rails, have you tried that?

Comment: And also, your code is not the actual markup in gist github, why? because you didn't put all the code.

Comment: I'm not sure what "an array of object" means? When I output the "cards" variable in the console, I get "Array(0)" which is a dropdown. Inside the dropdown it says "Length (0)" and lots of other stuff I don't understand. Does this mean the script is wrong and there are no objects in my array?

Comment: @colmtuite array with object value, see https://i.cubeupload.com/6OlH2B.png

Comment: I understand, thanks. I'm getting this in console https://i.cubeupload.com/3BTqrE.png. To get that I used console.log(cards)